# Calling a stateless EJB 3 annotated Remote in a local context

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ejb-3.0

I would like to know if the EJB 3 specification or the Weblogic vendor specificities give information about the performance/overhead cost of calling with a lookup a stateless EJB which is in a local context (in the same server and the same ear that the class invoking the EJB) but which is annotated Remote in its declaration.
I did many searches on the web on the subject and I didn't find a complete response.

Is it the invocation processing is the same that if the EJB was declared local ?
So, not expensive. 
Or, is the invocation processing is which of EJB remote invocation ? So, more expensive.

If you have references about this question, it would be great.

Comment: WebLogic Server is able to detect this situation  and change its behavior to improve performances.

Comment: Have you a Weblogic documentation reference about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling local optimisations is a Weblogic-specific setting. See:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/ejb/DDreference-ejb-jar.html#wp1113807

> When enable-call-by-reference is True, EJB methods called from within
>   the same EAR file or standalone JAR file will pass arguments by
>   reference. This improves the performance of method invocation since
>   parameters are not copied.

Enabling call by reference is [not strictly EJB Spec-compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251797/effect-of-enable-call-by-reference), since you can no longer guarantee that the parameters of a remote interface are actually clones of the original arguments, but may actually be the original objects, so be careful to make defensive copies if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for this precise answer.